# lessc binary not available after installing less via NPM

Tags: css, node.js, less, npm

I went ahead and installed and tested node.js and then I installed LESS CSS via NPM but when I type in the command

```
lessc styles.less
```

or

```
lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

It tells me `-bash: lessc: command not found`

I'm in MAC Lion Terminal program

**EDIT**:

After installing Node you need to run this command

```
ln -s ~/.npm/less/1.2.1/package/bin/lessc (path to directory you want)
```

Then you will be able to run less on any of the less files in that directory.

It works but it's not compiling the imports into one CSS file. It just leaves the imports in the file as is. I was hoping I could combine all of the CSS inside the files that I'm importing together.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal's session/reloaded your paths?

Comment: Whoops! No I didn't. I changed the question because I was able to figure it out. I just needed to install the less in the directories I wanted to use them in. I used this command ===> ln -s ~/.npm/less/1.2.1/package/bin/lessc (path to directory)

Comment: This is a bug with `npm/less` see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1464

Comment: Note that this problem can occur if you installed node through homebrew on Mac a while ago, new brew node installs should be ok - it's not a less bug, but it was a homebrew bug: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/21627

Answer (score 34):

When you install LESS via npm use the -g option to install it globally.

`npm install -g less`

Comment: Or if you don't want to pollute the system, install without `-g` then simply invoke `./node_modules/less/bin/lessc` from the directory you were under when doing `npm install less`

Answer (score 16):

When installing packages with `npm` you have two options:

1. Install them globally: `npm install -g <package>`
2. Install locally in your home directory under `~/.npm`: `npm install <package>`

If you choose option 1 your system should be able to locate the binary `lessc`. If you choose option 2 you should add `~/.npm/less/path_to_bin_directory` to your path:

```
export PATH=~/.npm/less/path_to_bin_directory:$PATH
```

or better, if a `~/node_modules` directory has been created as a result of installation:

```
export PATH=~/node_modules/less/path_to_bin_directory:$PATH
```