# lessc: command not found

Tags: node.js, less

I'm on OS X.8 and a newbie at Node & LESS.  I thought I installed lessc earlier and when I go to /usr/local/bin I see lessc

but for the life of me, I can't run it.  Anytime I do run it, I see
-bash: lessc: command not found

So I've tried the tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069104/lessc-binary-not-available-after-installing-less-via-npm) which has the following:

```
ln -s ~/.npm/less/1.3.3/package/bin/lessc my/local/dir
```

My local dir happens to be on a second drive on my laptop, here's the path:
/Volumes/Mac17/Users/denis2/Sites/staging/assets/less

With all that said, I try and run:

```
lessc boostrap.less
```

and still get

```
-bash: lessc: command not found
```

**I'm totally lost here and any help would be tremendous.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the steps :

1. Make lessc executable by your user(permission denied means you dont have permission to run) like `chmod 755 lessc`
2. Export the location of lessc into the PATH like `export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/folder/path/less/bin` (where lessc is present)
3. Use lessc `lessc boostrap.less`

You should put PATH export in environment so that you dont have to do it every time you login See here :
[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: This worked!  Once I chmod 755 that let me finally compile without issue.  I updated your line 3 to output a CSS file.  I read the other post on environment.plist but couldn't take away what to do exactly so I'll stick with what works for now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you enter just `lessc`, it is searched in the `$PATH`. For security reasons, the current directory is not in the `$PATH`. Try

```
./lessc bootstrap.less
```

or, if that doesn't work, simply

```
~/.npm/less/1.3.3/package/bin/lessc bootstrap.less
```

If you get a `Permission Denied` error then, you may need to mark the file as executable. Use

```
chmod a+x ~/.npm/less/1.3.3/package/bin/lessc
```

to do that. You may also need to call node directly, if it isn't in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Both generated errors.  The first snippet produced: -bash: ./lessc: No such file or directory

Comment: The second one produced -bash: /Users/denis/.npm/less/1.3.3/package/bin/lessc: Permission denied

Comment: Would this be because Node is installed on my primary startup drive but the less folder is on a secondary drive/volume?

Comment: @SWL Nope. See my updated answer. You may also want to have a look at lessc and check that its [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is correct.