# Pipeline Compile Error - "lessc: No such file or directory"

Tags: django, ubuntu, deployment, less

I'm trying to deploy django project using AWS S3 and Pipeline. When I try to `collectstatic`, I get error:

```
pipeline.exceptions.CompilerError: b'/usr/bin/env: lessc: No such file or directory\n'
```

After typing `which less`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/less
```

Could you help with fixing it?

Comment: Maybe try adding your profile? `source /home/USER/.profile` (or equivalent ) before you run anything

Comment: profile is already added, doesn't work anyway

Comment: system is looking for `lessc` yet you only have `/usr/bin/less`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lessc binary not available after installing less via NPM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069104/lessc-binary-not-available-after-installing-less-via-npm)

Comment: Sorry bud, i have 0 experience with pipeline.