# I can't use lessc to compile in terminal

Tags: less

I just install less by using

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

and call this to try compile file, but it get error

```
lessc '/home/annguyen/Desktop/test.less' >'/home/annguyen/Desktop/2.css' 
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'less' (>= 0.a) among 102 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/annguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0:/home/annguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/lessc:22:in `<main>'
```

how can i fix this, please help me

Comment: This looks like a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9069104/1848654 and having another `lessc` command (written in ruby) in your PATH.

Comment: i try all way in that but it not work

Comment: And don't use `>` there unless necessary (that's not your particular problem but this will cause some headaches for you in future). the proper command line usage is `lessc srcfile dstfile`.